# A namespace cannot directly contain members in the Azure Function App

Tags: azure, azure-functions

TARGET: Do the Azure Function tutorial on and copied code, but got several errors when executing locally on VS2017. I appreciate you help.

https://www.cyotek.com/blog/upload-data-to-blob-storage-with-azure-functions

ERROR 1 - related to `Run`:

> CS0116    A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods   UploadToBlobFunctionApp C:\AzureFunctions\UploadToBlobFunctionApp\UploadToBlobFunctionApp\UploadToBlobFunction.cs   15  Active

ERROR 2 - related to `Task CreateBlob`:

> CS0116    A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods   UploadToBlobFunctionApp 
>   C:\AzureFunctions\UploadToBlobFunctionApp\UploadToBlobFunctionApp\UploadToBlobFunction.cs   45  Active

ERROR 3 - related to `await CreateBlob`:

> CS0103    The name 'CreateBlob' does not exist in the current context UploadToBlobFunctionApp C:\AzureFunctions\UploadToBlobFunctionApp\UploadToBlobFunctionApp\UploadToBlobFunction.cs   36  Active

CODE `Function.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
HttpStatusCode result;
string contentType;

result = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;

contentType = req.Content.Headers?.ContentType?.MediaType;

if (contentType == "application/json")
{
    string body;

    body = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(body))
    {
        string name;

        name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n");

        await CreateBlob(name + ".json", body, log);

        result = HttpStatusCode.OK;
    }
}

return req.CreateResponse(result, string.Empty);
}

private async static Task CreateBlob(string name, string data, 
TraceWriter log)
{
string accessKey;
string accountName;
string connectionString;
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount;
CloudBlobClient client;
CloudBlobContainer container;
CloudBlockBlob blob;

accessKey = "qwertyw4VhRajxlZn9C4hTMB8oSwE4klNUsvTy9VeTCIQ11111vFVVGExDwJ+JUboFv2B79j+W6foqLWE92w==";
accountName = "mystorage";
connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=" + accountName + ";AccountKey=" + accessKey + ";EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);

client = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

container = client.GetContainerReference("functionupload");

await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(name);
blob.Properties.ContentType = "application/json";

using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data)))
{
    await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The example that you are referencing is using scripted functions (`csx` file). They are mostly used while editing code directly in Azure portal.

I think you are trying to create a precompiled application with `csproj` and `cs` files. In this case, your code should be a valid C#, i.e. all methods should be inside classes.

Have a look at [this example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/Precompiled-functions).

You can also use attributes to mark your functions and triggers instead of authoring `function.json` manually, see examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library).

Comment: It seem like I don't have function.json file at all in VS2017 Azure Functions project with HTTP Trigger. How to create?

Comment: Use attribute-based model as described in my last link. Install `Azure Functions Visual Studio 2017 Tools` which will help you.

Comment: I do have function.json file under debug and I do have function tools in VS2017. I have another code in same env doing same erros. It has methods inside classes. 
namespace CopyFileFromADLSToBlob
{
    public static class CopyFileFromADLSToBlob
    {

Comment: @Keke are you new to C# ??